# How can I limit the use of Emberjs to only a few pages of my website?

Tags: ember.js

I run a website served by Django, and almost all the logic exists on the server side.
However, I have a few pages that are AJAX centric (for instance the comments page), and over time such pages have grown to be too messy, with multiple nested AJAX callbacks, and heavy DOM manipulation.

It's too hard to maintain, so I decided to give Emberjs a try.

I would like to avoid having some JS files that are linked only by the pages that need them, because I compress all my JS in one minified file, that I serve.

Is there a way to not initialize Emberjs if I don't need it?

For instance, here some HTML:

```
<p>
  I don't need ember in this page!
</p>​
```

And some JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: "hello"
});
Ctrl = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function() {
        alert("Ember is initialized anyway.");
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JYvSE/

The `alert` in my controller's `init` function is executed. I could put this in my HTML:

```
<div id="ember-enabled"></div>
```

and then in my controller I could do:

```
if($('#ember-enabled') === undefined) return;
```

but that would spare me the controller code, not the Emberjs initialization.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a module system like minispade or require.js, and only require your "main" ember app module on the pages where you want it. The main module would be the one that `require`s the ember application and other core modules.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a great link. minispade is lacking in tutorials. The JS itself is only 67 lines long: https://github.com/wycats/minispade/blob/master/lib/main.js. You will probably want to use it with something that can convert JS files to minispade modules -- a packaging system like rake-pipeline, iridium, or perhaps something provided by django?

Comment: Thanks...Is there any boilerplate/template kind of thing which has ember, minispade & rake-pipeline all together ?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton. You might also be interested in this blog post: http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/08/10/iridium/

Comment: Here's another one I found: http://blog.nulayer.com/post/23294069876/building-simple-javascript-libraries-with-rake-pipeline

Comment: Thanks alot I liked Iridium very much though... & I'd like to integrate coffeescript into Iridium, any suggestions on how to ? or is there any skeleton available ? There is one brunch-ember-sassy https://github.com/mmuddasir/brunch-ember-sassy... but I am more inclined to Iridium+coffee...Thanks in advance :)

Comment: iridium uses rake-pipeline and you can generate and customize the Assetfile. The rake-pipeline-web-filters project has a coffeescript filter: https://github.com/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters/blob/master/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/coffee_script_filter.rb

Comment: ok Thanks :) that looks great then ! i'll give it a shot then, nd by the way saw your yapp.com, waiting for beta pin & idea seems great btw , Good Luck :D

Comment: I have successfully setup the Iridium, I think I am missing some tweaking pertaining to handlebars, because console logs the following error "Unable to find view at path..." may be I am not able to precompile my handlebars, any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: I've not used Iridium personally, so I'm not sure. You might consider opening an issue on the iridium repo.